# A question related to eigen-expansion and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

My question comes from page 28 of the lecture notes "Entropy Methods" written by CHRISTIAN SCHMEISER. Specifically, with the notation $z := (x, v) \in \mathbb{R}^{2d}$, I didn't see why we have $$|x|^2 + |v|^2 + x\cdot v = z^{tr}Pz, \quad \text{with} \quad P = \sum_{j=1}^{2d} p_j \otimes \overline{p_j}.$$ Here $z^{tr}$ means the transpose of $z$ and $\overline{p_j}$ denotes the conjugate transpose (I think so). What confuses me is that I have no issue seeing $$ |x|^2 + |v|^2 + x\cdot v = z^{tr}Qz, \quad \text{with} \quad Q = \begin{pmatrix} I_d & \frac 12\,I_d \\ \frac 12\,I_d & I_d \end{pmatrix},$$ but how does one arrive at the advertised representation/decomposition involving eigenvectors of the transpose of $C$?

Comment: Not a complete answer since I'm not quite sure where to go next from here. 
I think basically what you need to show is that $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf Q$.

But, letting $\lambda_k$ be the associated eigenvalue of the eigenvector $\mathrm p_k$ of $\mathbf{C}$, we should have
$$P^i{}_j=\sum_k \frac{1}{{\lambda_k}^2}\left(C^i{}_l(p_k)^l\right)\left(C^i{}_l\left(\overline{p_k}\right)^l\right)$$
Where I have used Einstein summation. I'm not quite sure how to show this is $=Q^i{}_j$.

Comment: @K.defaoite thanks for your attempt. I think trying to show $P = Q$ might be too hard (if possible), basically to show something like $x^TAx =x^TBx$ for **a specific** $x$ does not require us to show $A =B$